# Class design : Decide between file and database for storage during runtime

Tags: object-oriented, class-design, file-handling, backend

Based on the *demo* or *license* version of my application, I am supposed to either save the `data` to a `file (xml)` at a specific location or a `relational database`. What should be my approach for this case in respect to `class design`? I assume using `strategy pattern` will be suitable in this case.

Comment: How complex is your data schema? One or two tables? Twenty tables? Two hundred, with several views and stored procedures? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using something like the Strategy or Adapter pattern seems sensible here.

1. Define an interface (or a family of interfaces) that describes all persistence operations of your business logic.
2. Create implementations of this interface for a database backend and the file backend.
3. On startup of your application, use dependency injection techniques to supply the correct implementation to the business logic, depending on licensing status. This can be as simple as

   ```
   IRepository repo = (isTrialVersion) ? new FileRepository("data.txt")
                                       : new DatabaseRepository("connection string");
   runApplication(repo, otherConfiguration);
   ```

If the persistence interface is more complicated and has to consist of multiple interfaces, you might inject a Facade or Abstract Factory object.

The exact name of the pattern you use is not important, the relevant part is “use an interface and supply the correct implementation at runtime”.

If the demo version and full version are distributed as separate programs, you could also select the correct implementation at build time using conditional compilation techniques. This is probably overkill in most cases, but could be a viable option e.g. in C++. Note that conditional compilation will complicate testing.

This answer assumes that you are interested in an elegant solution. It is however easily crackable. But there's no good solution to avoid cracking if you give your software to other people. If that is a concern to you, consider distributing the license-dependent parts as a separate library (DLL) or use a SaaS distribution model.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about [Data Access Object](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html) Design pattern

> Use a Data Access Object (DAO) to abstract and encapsulate all access to the data source. The DAO manages the connection with the data source to obtain and store data.

The diagram for using DAO:

[image]

You can create Data Access Object strategy using Factory Method:

[image]